# (#200) response The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: android, facebook

I'm implementing facebook in my apps. Login with no problem through facebook managed to get the response from it. When try to post feed the error state as below: i tried many way all not working. please help me.

```
 public class main extends Activity{
        static Session session;
        Activity aty;
        Context context;
        protected static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
        protected boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;

    private FacebookloginDelegate delegate;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    publishFeedDialog();


    }



    public void loginWithFacebook() {
        // start Facebook Login
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {



                      Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                          // callback after Graph API response with user object
                          @Override
                          public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                            if (user != null) {
                                 if (delegate!=null) 
                                     delegate.onCompletedProgress(user, response);
//                               Toast.makeText(activity, "Sharing to Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                                  publishFeedDialog(activity, fl);
                                 publishFeedDialog();
                            }
                          }
                        }).executeAsync();
             }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }
//  
    public void setDelegate(FacebookloginDelegate delegate_)
    {
        delegate = delegate_;
    }

    protected boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
        for (String string : subset) {
            if (!superset.contains(string)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static abstract class FacebookloginDelegate {
        protected void onCompletedProgress(GraphUser user,
                Response response) {}
    }

    public void publishFeedDialog() 
    {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        //if session is not empty and it is opened
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()){

            postOnWall();

        }
        else
        {
            // login with facebook if no session is available
            loginWithFacebook();
        }
    }  




    public void postOnWall() {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("caption", "My Caption");
        params.putString("description", "description here");
        params.putString("picture", "http://test.com");
        params.putString("name", "name string");
        params.putString("message", "my message here");




        session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if(session != null && session.isOpened()){          
            // Check for publish permissions
            if(!session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions"))   {           
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS));
                Log.d("FBAUTOPOST","FBAUTOPOST");
            }

            Request postToWall = new Request(session,"me/feed", params, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i("FB AutoPost:", "FBAUTOPOST" + response.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(main.this, "Content post successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //session.close();
                }
            });
            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(postToWall);
            task.execute(); 
        }

    }
```

Error msg :

```
07-26 18:42:02.705: I/FB AutoPost:(4348): FBAUTOPOST{Response:  responseCode: 403, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action}, isFromCache:false}
```

This error code appear after post response from facebook. I have added in app_id in my string.xml. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most permissions need to get approved by Facebook before you can use them for Users. Without approval, those permissions only work for App Admins. Check out the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

> Apps requesting more than public_profile, email and the user_friends permission must be reviewed by Facebook before those permissions can be requested from people

Review Guidelines: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Comment: i have 2 apps the first apps no need to review manage to publish with this code. Is it just latest updated this?

Comment: what do you mean? you need to go through the review process for every single app - but only if you are using extended permissions (something else than public_profile, email or user_friends)

Comment: i mean currently i have another apps with different app_id no need go through the review process but still able to post. Any idea for this? same code only different app_id

Comment: then that other app is either old (created before may 2014) or you are using it as admin.

Comment: apps created before may 2014 still don´t need to get reviews, until april 2015.

Comment: how to used it as admin? so that i'm able to publish without any process?

Comment: well, you just need to login and use the api with a user who got a role in the app (admin, developer, whatever)

Comment: i add an user as developer and manage to share. Any way i can open to public without review?

Comment: of course not. that would make the whole review process void ;) - unless you don´t use extended permissions, then you don´t need review and you can put your app public without any delay.

Comment: any idea why i cant create an apps using facebook developer account and with this error "Please use your personal account to create this app. To use a different name for testing, create the app with your personal account and then create a test account.

Comment: did you switch to a page or business account on facebook?

Comment: i just login to facebook using my new created personal account and go to manage apps then click on create an apps. The error msg pop out.

Comment: "new created personal account"? what does that mean, did you not have an account before? not sure if that solves your problem, but you have to verify your account in order to become a developer and create apps (with phone number, for example)

Comment: yes i have verified my phone number. I have an account but i try to create another for developer purpose.

Comment: fake accounts are not allowed on facebook. why not just use your real account? you cannot verify 2 accounts with the same phone number anyway, i guess.